# Adding a custom style to an element in an existing theme in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I don't think this has been asked before, if so please redirect me. I'm new to WPF, and I've tried everything I could think of with no success, I'm stuck.

I'm using a **WPF Theme**, and I want to add some **custom styles** I created to it. For example, all `TextBlock` are supposed to have *Red* foreground, but I have a group of `TextBlock` that I want in *Blue*.

So far I've been doing this in the xaml, creating a `<Style></Style>` in the **resources**, and calling it using `Style="{StaticResource StyleName}"`. But I want to add it to the theme files instead, and I don't know how to give it a name and call it from the xaml.

I guess I'd start with something like this, but how do I link both elements?

In the theme file (MyStyles.xaml or TextEdit.xaml or similar):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="KeyName" ???>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

And then in **my** xaml:

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlockName"
      Style="{???}">
</TextBlock>
```

I need this style to be in the Theme because the program will allow users to change themes, and these styles can't hardcoded be in the xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to first merge that resource file into your resources :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <dxc:IntToBooleanConverter x:Key="IntToBooleanConverter" />
        (...)
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and then you can use it with

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Style="{StaticResource KeyName}" />
```

Comment: Would the file change automatically if I swap the theme?

Comment: @yisela Yes, that's what I use to keep my styles central and make sure my application looks consistently the same between windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have loaded your Theme file you can access any of the Styles/Resources the same way as local Styles/Resources

If you use `Style="{StaticResource StyleName}"` it will look first in the Window/UserControl, if not found it will look though the loaded Resource dictionaries. so as long as you have loaded the Theme (Resource Dictionary) it will work fine.